# How to get client site control id without added runat="server" in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to get the client site control ID in vb.net code behind. without added runat="server" .

```
 <div id="flip"></div>
```

Comment: Essentially, you don't: without `runat="server"`, the server doesn't know about the element. Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: You're writing server side codes, but refuse to add `runat="server"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can not access `div` / html elements without runat="server" on server side. You better make it `runat="server"` and use `ClientID` for client side script.

If you have framework 4 or above you can try using [ClientIDMode="static"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) to keep the Client id unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

runat="server" means that control is server control that means it maintains viewstate to store value and it is transferred between client and server in regular request and responses.

So in order to get the value of control you must be used server control why because it maintains viewstate, if you don't use runat="server" its like html control and the value will be lost for every request and response why because it doesn't maintain viewstate.

So use server control and get id by using clientid.

More about Server control see

http://extremeexperts.com/net/faq/diffbetweenserverandhtmlcontrols.aspx

[Html control and asp.net web control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323788/html-control-and-asp-net-web-control)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301325.aspx

Comment: I am using toggle for div . If add runat="server " then toggle is not working.

Comment: so use hidden field(server control) and store that value into hidden field.